# Top Margin Not Moving on Both Divs

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have two divs, 'about-wrap' and 'tc-wrap'. I can change the top-margin of about-wrap but not tc-wrap. I have found an old question that said that you needed to float the divs, but about-wrap works without it, and tc-wrap doesn't work with it. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="about-wrap">
        <div class="about">
            <p></br><h1><bold>About Us</bold></h1></p>

            <p class="about-us"><h5>Next Gen was founded in late 2014 by nG Fearr (then known as nG FearIess). It began as an XBox 360 clan, now trying to grow in XBox One. We are multi-COD players, and play Modern Warfare 3 and 2, Advanced Warfare and mainly Black Ops 2. Although Next Gen began with only 1 founding member, it has rapidly grown and currently has over 25 clan members. 
            </br></br>
            In Next Gen, our primary focus is sniping/feeding. We currently have an RC and are looking for snipers. If you would like to join, please submit your clips and contact us. For information about try outs, please contact our leader at nextgengaming@tryout.com .</h5></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tc-wrap">
    <div class="tc">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#about-wrap {
width: 58.5%;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-top: 6%;
}

.about h1 {
    font-family: "Bitter";
    color: #000b22;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.about h5 {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: #3d4942;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.tc {
    width: 21%;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    float: right;
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong.. thanks.

Comment: you are used two time on width `#about-wrap` and `.tc`... which width you want?

Comment: @user10 whoops, my mistake.. I'll edit my post now

Comment: this is the fixed height which stops you to remove margen check here http://jsfiddle.net/bqspgchv/

Comment: Yo. Set float: left; to both of your wraps and your problem should be fixed!

http://jsfiddle.net/wre0mcx9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed

```
#about-wrap {
width: 58.5%;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-top: 6%;
}

.about h1 {
    font-family: "Bitter";
    color: #000b22;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.about h5 {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: #3d4942;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.tc {
    width: 21%;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    float: right;
}
```

to this

```
#about-wrap {
    width: 58.5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.about h1 {
    font-family: "Bitter";
    color: #000b22;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

.about h5 {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: #3d4942;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#tc-wrap {
    float: right;
    width: 31%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
```

I kept the HTML the same. Here is the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/qmq11vu5/).